# Explain CATransform3D matrix each elements represents

Tags: swift, transformation

I am working on Transform to CALayer using CATransform3D matrix.

```
CATransform3D(m11:1, m12:0, m13:0, m14:g/i,
                               m21:0, m22:1, m23:0, m24:h/i,
                               m31:0, m32:0, m33:1, m34:0,
                                m41:0, m42:0, m43:0, m44:1.0)
```

i need to know each elements represents for what? like Scale, Translation, Rotation, and Perspective? and need to know m14, m24 are for what?

Comment: Look up "transformation matrix" and learn how it works.

Answer (score 0):

- m14 - x translation
- m24 - y translation

Other parameters are pretty much the same as the 2D transform matrix, but in 3D you have Z axis
[image: 2D affine transformation matrix]